# Java if/else statement

Tags: java, class, if-statement, superclass

I am working on my final project in a computer class and am trying to implement a basic if/else statement in a nested class but it is only opting to use the else case.
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class CollegeApplication {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       //create object by default constructor
       College c1 = new College();
       //create object by overloaded constructor
       College c2 = new College("Frostburg", "Frostburg", "MD", 5142);
       College c3 = new College("UMBC", "Baltimore", "MD", 14000);
       //set the information of object 1
       c1.setName("Full Sail");
       c1.setCity("Winter Park");
       c1.setState("FL");
       c1.setStudent_Body(19285);

       System.out.println("Enter your states two-letter abbreviation");
       String user_State = scan.nextLine();

       c1.printCollege();
       System.out.println();
       c2.printCollege();
       System.out.println();
       c3.printCollege();
   }
}
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
import java.util.Scanner;

public class College {

   // private data members
   private String name;
   private String city;
   private String state;
   private int student_Body;
   private String tuition;
   private String user_State;

   // default constructor which set the data member to default value
   public College() {

       this.name = "";
       this.city = "";
       this.state = "";
       this.student_Body = 0;
       this.tuition = "";
       this.user_State = "";
   }

   // parameterized constructor
   public College(String name, String city, String state, int student_Body) {
       super();
       this.name = name;
       this.city = city;
       this.state = state;
       this.student_Body = student_Body;
   }

   // getter and setter
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public String getCity() {
       return city;
   }

   public void setCity(String city) {
       this.city = city;
   }

   public String getState() {
      return state;
   }

   public void setState(String state) {
      this.state = state;  
   }

   public int getStudent_Body() {
       return student_Body;
   }

   public void setStudent_Body(int student_Body) {
       this.student_Body = student_Body;
   }    
   // print college data
   public void printCollege() {

       System.out.println("Name of College: " + name);
       System.out.println("City of Collge: " + city);
       System.out.println("State of Collge: " + state);
       System.out.println("Student Body Count: " + student_Body);

   this.user_State = user_State;
      if (state.equals(user_State)) {
         this.tuition = "Eligible";
      }
      else {
         this.tuition = "Ineligible";
      }

       System.out.println("In-State Tuition: " + tuition); 
   }
}
```

If anyone could help id be greatly appreciative in knowing how to alter the if statement to not only print ineligible

Comment: You should pass `user_State ` to printCollege method, like `printCollege(String user_State)`

Comment: c1.printCollege(String user_State);
       System.out.println();
       c2.printCollege(String user_State);
       System.out.println();
       c3.printCollege(String user_State);          
   =-=-=-=-=-=-==-=-=      
   CollegeApplication.java:21: error: illegal start of expression
       public String user_State = "";
       ^

Comment: you shouldn't specify a type when calling a method. So replace this with:

c1.printCollege(user_State); System.out.println(); c2.printCollege(user_State); System.out.println(); c3.printCollege(user_State);

Answer (score 0):

This question does not contain a question but I see the problem area.

Ask yourself why your `College` has both a `state` and a `user_State`. Why would this class have an aspect of itself be a user_State? There isn't even a getter and setter for it (as there shouldn't be).

```
public void printCollege() {

   this.user_State = user_State;
      if (state.equals(user_State)) {
         this.tuition = "Eligible";
      }
      else {
         this.tuition = "Ineligible";
      }

       System.out.println("In-State Tuition: " + tuition); 
   }
```

This function takes no input and gives no output, but has side-effects of printing something and modifying fields.

The only other time user_State is referenced in `College` is when it's set to the empty string.

```
this.user_State = "";
```

And that's only when a `College` object is constructed with the default constructor. If a `College` object is made using the argument constructor, `user_State` remains `null`.

Anyway, this method begins by setting this empty string (or null) to itself:

```
this.user_State = user_State;
```

So it's just going to be the empty string (or null).

Next it compares the strings `state` with the empty string or null in `user_State`.

```
if (state.equals(user_State)) {
```

`state` is not equal to the empty string nor null in any of your test cases, so it continues to the else clause:

```
else {
    this.tuition = "Ineligible";
}
```

What you probably intend is for `printCollege()` to take the `user_State` variable you asked the user for. In which case it does not take 0 arguments, it takes 1 string argument.

```
public void printCollege(String userState) {

      if (state.equals(userState)) {
         this.tuition = "Eligible";
      }
      else {
         this.tuition = "Ineligible";
      }

       System.out.println("In-State Tuition: " + tuition); 
   }
```

and the invocations of `printCollege(String userState)` should be done as appropriate, with the input you received from the user.

Please follow Java naming conventions in the future, something like `user_State` should just be `userState`.

Answer (score 0):

1. there is no setter method for user_State instance variable
2. no parameter provided for initialization of user_State instance variable

so if condition fails as it considers user_State variable as instance variable it will always be "" in case of default constructor and "null" in case of parameterized constructor

**either**

> provide parameter to `printCollege()` method according to @PatricChen

**or**

> remove the statement `this.user_State = user_State` from
>   `printCollege()` and provide setter method for user_State variable and
>   a user_State parameter to parameterized constructor of College class